# scanner driver Samsung Xpress M267X/287X

Tags: macos, driver, scanning

I don’t get the Samsung Xpress M267X/287X scanner to work with 10.8. The scanner shows up in Image Capture but it need additional software, which it can’t find.

Does someone has a link to the right drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to download this from Samsung's support center. There were new scan drivers released 9th of April this year and they can be found here:
http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SL-M2875FD/XAA

Remember to follow the instructions supported by Samsung:

> > Security setting should be changed in order to install drivers in Mac OS X 10.8:
> >
> > Run [System Preferences] under [Application] folder
> >
> > Select [Security & Privacy]
> >
> > Select [Anywhere] under [Allow applications downloaded from]